# Как создать границу у тени за блоком

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

Подскажите, как сделать вот такой блок как на изображении. Сам блок с border, у него соответственно тень, в примере она розовая, и у тени граница(border). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="flex_items_block_rgb_1"></div>

.flex_items_block_rgb_1{
max-width: 100%;
border: 3px solid #000;
background: #FFF;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: -10px -10px #AE56CF;
}
```

Comment: Вы сами-то пытались?

Comment: Конечно, и попробовал через box-shadow и через псевдокласс before, но не выходит

Comment: Ну так а где ваш код? Предлагаете всё с нуля сделать вместо вас? ))

Comment: Да, вы правы, не подумал, подправил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #76aaf0 0%, #c738c0 100%);
}

.test {
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: 80%;
  aspect-ratio: 4/1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 
    -10px -10px 0 0 #ad55ce,
    -11px -11px 0 2px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!